# Почему самописных 3д библиотек с использованием рейкастинга много, а с использованием растеризации только openGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

Я наблюдаю следующее: огромное количество людей пишут свои библиотеки для 3д графики на основе рейкастинга. Но почему они не пишут библиотеки 3д графики с использованием растеризации? Я знаю только одну библиотеку использующую растеризацию, и это OpenGL. Почему так происходит? Неужели растеризация намного сложнее рейкастинга, да на столько, что библиотек с рейкастингом полно, а с растеризацией единицы?

Дополнено: когда я сказал "самописные, это значит они написаны простыми людьми, а не известными компаниями по типу того же OpenGL

Comment: А как же directx, vulkan, metal? Их не пишут все кому не лень потому, что нужно договориться с производителями видеокарт, чтобы реализовали их в своих драйверах.

Comment: Нужны примеры таких библиотек для рейкастинга. Это какие-то самоделки, или что-то серьезное?

Comment: OpenGL это не библиотека, а спецификация. Ну и библиотек для растеризации, как собак не резанных. Например agg, freetype, cairo, tinygl и т.п. Хотя программная растеризация для именно треугольников на практике не особо полезна, так как уже давно везде доступны аппаратные реализации.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а при чем тут реализация их в драйверах? Фактически OpenGL и любая библиотека рейкастинга делают одно и тоже, только по другим алгоритмам. Зачем обязательно в драйвера то? Можно все на процессоре обрабатывать

Comment: *"Зачем"* Чтобы не тормозило? Зачем, по вашему, видеокарты в компьютеры ставят, если можно на процессоре рисовать?